# How to efficiently toggle classes with multiple HTML elements across multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am toggling an arrow image whenever my `div` is clicked. I am controlling the state of the click with

```
const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false)
```

My div has an `onClick` function that controls the state and toggles the `faq-subject-toggle-arrow` class that adds an image

```
<div className={`faq-subject ${toggleArrow ? 'faq-subject-toggle-arrow' : ''}`} onClick={() => {
  setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow)
}>
```

My problem is that I have 50 `div`s across multiple styles and don't want to make 50 states to toggle one image.

Is there a more efficient solution for this with less code?

Comment: turn this code into one component and use it multiple times. so the state can live inside each component and does not affect each other

Comment: You can achieve this but having this div in a separate  component and manage that state in that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created something that does the same thing. I extracted your code and made a component. now the state lives inside the component and will not affect others.

[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dijkstra-9m8dp?file=/src/button.js)

component

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const Button = () => {
  const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px", margin: "10px" }}
      className={`faq-subject ${toggleArrow ? "faq-subject-toggle-arrow" : ""}`}
      onClick={() => {
        setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow);
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

css file, I didn't have the same classes so I created mine.

```
.faq-subject {
  background: blue;
}
.faq-subject-toggle-arrow {
  background: orange;
}
```

now you can use it wherever you want for multiple times

```
import { Button } from "./button";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button />
      <Button />
      <Button />
      <Button />
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}
```